# CSS with SystemJS / jspm

Tags: javascript, jspm, systemjs

I created a small project using jspm/systemjs partly based on the following article:
http://developer.telerik.com/featured/choose-es6-modules-today/
and
http://jspm.io/docs/getting-started.html

I have installed bootstrap (jspm install bootstrap), have installed the jspm css plugin and am using http-server from npm to serve it locally. I have tried the following lines in my start.js:

```
import 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!';
import 'bootstrap.css!';
import 'jspm_packages/github/twbs/bootstrap@3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css!';
```

The request that arrives in each case is:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/twbs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css

Which the local http_server is not finding.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: the first one above worked (import 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!';) but I didn't try them in that order and I had forgotten to turn off browser cache.